# Solving plain js "asynchronous" Ajax requests waiting for one another

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, prototypejs

an application I'm working on features a dashboard on its main page. To avoid load issues, the dashboard's content is to be calculated asynchronously via Ajax, allowing users not to wait for it to be ready to go to another page, or to wait for a slow component to check out the indicators on lighter ones.

It is supposed to work like this:

- the page loads. The onload() on body includes a javascript function making an Ajax request that generates a canvas/skeleton for the dashboard, with simple content for each component (basically a loading gif and "Wait, loading content... " message), and information (using hidden form fields) on the component (refresh delay, wrapper div id, component class, etc.)
- this Ajax call has an onSuccess part, calling another function. This one scans for the "hidden information" and, for each component found, calls a 3rd function to "refresh" (thus on the first call it replaces the default content) its content.
- In short, if my dashboard has 4 components, when I go to that page an Ajax request creates a canvas, then calls a function which scans the canvas, and fires 4 Ajax requests each one calculating a div's content (component).

Normally, I can click a link and go to another page whenever I want, seeing how the calls are asynchronous so I as the user keep control. The components also update asap since every individual Ajax call is asynchronous too.
However, whenever I click a link it waits for the calls to be over before it processes it and goes to the new page, forcing the user to wait for the (sometimes long) loading. The "refresh" calls are also handled sequentially, instead of concurrently.

How do I get "real" asynchrony? At first I read that Ajax is asynchronous by default but that you can specify "asynchronous: true", I tried it and it didn't change anything.
For what it's worth, we are mostly using IE7 ("quirks mode" IE8 because of the people we got the application from neglecting to use a doctype and coding in such a way that including one makes the application unusable).
Here's the code:

```
function create_dashboard() {
    var param = [...];
    options = {
        method: 'post',
        postBody: param,
        asynchronous: true,
        evalJS: true,
        onSuccess: function(return) {
            setTimeout(function(){tallyRefreshes()}, 100);
            setTimeout(function(){[switch a css class on some wrapper]}, 100);
        }
     };
    new Ajax.Updater('cadre_tdb','../php/dashboard/ajax/dashboard_manager.ajax.php', options);
}

function tallyRefreshes() {
    // for each component to refresh, gather its information
    elems = document.getElementsByClassName('dash_refresh_info');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        wrapper = elems[i].getElementsByClassName('dash_refresh_info_wrapper')[0].value;
        component_class = elems[i].getElementsByClassName('dash_refresh_info_class')[0].value;
        delay = elems[i].getElementsByClassName('dash_refresh_info_delay')[0].value;
        // send the info to a function which will trigger content refreshes at regular intervals
        refreshComponent(wrapper, component_class);
        if (delay > 0) {
            createRefreshTimer(wrapper, component_class, delay);
        }
    }
}

function refreshComponent(id_wrapper, component_class) {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById(id_wrapper);
    wrapper.innerHTML = '<div class="dashboard_loading">&nbsp;</div><span>Please wait, loading component...</span>';

    var param = [...];
    options = {
        method: 'post', postBody: param, asynchronous: true, evalJS: true };
    new Ajax.Updater(id_wrapper,'../php/dashboard/ajax/dashboard_manager.ajax.php', options);
}
```

The components only refresh themselves (through refreshComponent()) one after the other, instead of concurrently, and until they are all finished the user doesn't have control, being unable to change pages through clicking on links.
How can I make this *truly* asynchronous?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an IE7 expert but what you're describing is highly unlikely to happen. At least modern browsers will never wait for requests to finish when leaving a page.

Comment: You might also look at the server that is providing the content - the server might not be processing all the content at the same time and waiting for each request to finish before processing the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on the (now solved) issue : while it didn't come from the server, it was indeed an issue of sequentiality. The Ajax calls used the PHP session, and I learnt that it is managed with a file, meaning the session is "locked" and unaccessible for another page if it's already being accessed with writing rights.

Since I only used it to serve as a cache for the current user profile (check for it, if it's defined get it, if not define it and get it), I added session_write_close() after the last writing access, to "free up" the session. This allowed all my calls to happen "simultaneously" since they could start after the session usage (short and right at the beginning) instead of waiting for the whole script (taking up to 5s of execution for some components), and I could click links to other pages (which required the session too) and have it happen seemingly without any delay.
Thanks for the server suggestion, even if it wasn't the issue it put me on tracks!